# Setting up LDAP-Apache Directory with Worklight?

Tags: ldap, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have a LDAP-Apache Directory Studio setup on my Windows 7. Please find Screen Shot for two users i have created on LDAP[image]. I want to authenticate LDAP Login Module with LDAP server. I have created a user but i am unable to configure it properly on my worklight application-descriptor. I have followed documents provided by IBM Official site but still some how i am unable to do it. I have tried following xml data:

```
        <loginModule name="LDAPLoginModule">
                                <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule</className>
                                <parameter name="ldapProviderUrl" value="ldap://127.0.0.1:10389"/>
                                <parameter name="ldapTimeoutMs" value="5000"/>
                                <parameter name="ldapSecurityAuthentication" value="simple"/>
                                <parameter name="validationType" value="searchPattern"/> 

                                <parameter name="ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern" value="uid=localadmin,ou=users,ou=system,dc=example,dc=com"/>           
                                <parameter name="ldapSearchFilterPattern" value="(&amp;(uid={username})(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)"/>     
                                <parameter name="ldapSearchBase" value="dc=example,dc=com"/>           
                    </loginModule>
```

I have a less knowledge about LDAP so i am stuck with it.

---------------------------------Updated with soln from Kayyagari----------------------------

I have tried as per your suggestion , But I am now getting a different Error , I have posted the Logs for the same , Could you please help me

```
Worklight Console Logs

[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 0.010 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://INFAR20658.nmumarl.lntinfotech.com:10080/module_23_2_LDAPLoginModule/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application LDAPLoginModuleProject has stopped successfully.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 0.028 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://INFAR20658.nmumarl.lntinfotech.com:10080/module_23_2_LDAPLoginModule/
[WARNING ] Using empty value for configuration property 'ssl.keystore.path'
[WARNING ] Using empty value for configuration property 'ssl.keystore.password'
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application LDAPLoginModuleProject started in 1.707 seconds.
[WARNING ] FWLSE0138W: LdapLoginModule authentication failed. Reason 'java.lang.Exception: searchPattern
    at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule.login(LdapLoginModule.java:162)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext.invokeLoginModule(LoginContext.java:236)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext.processRequest(LoginContext.java:200)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRequest(AuthenticationContext.java:274)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:148)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4499)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your users are under ou=system, so change the values for "ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern" and "ldapSearchBase" as hown below

```
<parameter name="ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern" value="uid=localadmin,ou=users,ou=system"/>
<parameter name="ldapSearchBase" value="ou=system"/>
```

Comment: Hi the previous issue has been resolved but now i am facing another error ,which i have updated in the above question , could you please help me with the same as well please